# bash-completion only after sourcing .bash_profile

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, bash, tab-completion

I have bash-completion installed using macports and following lines in my .bash_profile

```
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

but the completion doesn't work when I open Terminal, however it starts working after sourcing .bash_profile or after 'bash -l'.

I'm running OSX 10.6, in Terminal preferences there is "Shell opens with: Default login shell (/usr/bin/login)" selected.

---

**Solved:** What I missed is line in [How to use bash-completion](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion)

> Make sure you add this after any PATH manipulation as otherwise the bash-completion will not work correctly.

when I moved the lines after PATH manipulation everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `chsh` command to make sure your shell is actually Bash; if your shell is `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`, Bash will mimic a historical shell, and won't read `~/.bash_profile`.

From `man bash`:

> If **bash** is invoked with the name **sh**, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of **sh** as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well. When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the **--login** option, it  first  attempts  to read and execute commands from */etc/profile* and *~/.profile*, in that order.
>
> [...]
>
> Since a shell invoked as **sh** does not attempt to read and execute  commands from any other startup files, the **--rcfile** option has no effect.

Comment: The account's default shell can be changed in *System Preferences » Accounts » Right-click your entry » Advanced…*. It's `/bin/bash` by default.

Comment: My shell is '/bin/bash' and the '~/.bash_profile' is read, everything (aliases, prompt) but bash completion works fine.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I wasn't sure if the default shell had changed since 10.4. @liborw: Can you make your full ~/.bash_profile available? Editing the information from your last comment into the original post would be helpful as well.